# How can I get valious type of data from Dictionary is coming from NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'd like to get data from dictionary which came from NSKeyedUnarchiver. Is there any solution?
My code is followed.

```
class Test: NSObject {

    var intData: Int
    var stringData: String

    .
    .
    .

    func updateData() {
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject([
            "intData": self.intData,
            "stringData": self.stringData,
        ], toFile: _path())
    }

    func loadData() {
        let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(_path)
        // --> error: I can't get data["intData"] :(
        self.intData = data["intData"].hasValue ? data["intData"] : 0
        self.stringData = data["stringData"].hasValue ? data["stringData"] : ""
    }
}
```

If you have any good idea, I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 1):

`unarchiveObjectWithFile` returns `AnyObject?` so you need to unwrap it

change your code to be

```
let data: AnyObject? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(_path)
if let unwrapData: AnyObject = data {
    self.intData = unwrapData["intData"] as Int
    self.stringData = unwrapData["stringData"] as String
}
```

**Note:** Cast the data returned from the subscript to Int or String

---

The above should work because `intData` and `stringData` are not optionals

In case they are Optionals then you will need to check on them

```
self.intData = (unwrapData["intData"] as? Int) != nil ? unwrapData["intData"] as? Int : 0
self.stringData = (unwrapData["stringData"] as? String) != nil ? unwrapData["stringData"] as? String : ""
```

which will put 0 or "" if not found

**OR**

```
self.intData = unwrapData["intData"] as? Int
self.stringData = unwrapData["stringData"] as? String
```

Which will be nil if not found